# Can't access UITableView Datasource methods using delegate of UISegmentedControl

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I am using a UISegmentedControl in my viewController. With one segment selected, I want the Table's data to be loaded from the NSFetchedResultsController (already setup), and from the other segment, I want data to be loaded from an array.

I am using the segment's delegate method here

```
- (void)segmentedControl:(SVSegmentedControl*)segmentedControl didSelectIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

The problem here is I can't seem to acces the tableView data source methods using the segment's delegate.

For example, it would be good if in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, I could do something like if (selectedSegment == 1), then xxxxx.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

I want to push to a different view when a row is selected depending on the segment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've synthesized your segmented control as a property, you can certainly access it from your tableView data source methods.

For example, if your segment is called `userSegment` you would just do

```
self.userSegment.selectedSegmentIndex
```

And then proceed accordingly. e.g. `if(self.userSegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {...} else {...}`. There are a variety of methods you can do with this index, too. Check out the documentation. One easy example:

```
NSString *selectedTitle = [self.userSegment titleForSegmentAtIndex:self.userSegment.selectedSegmentIndex];
```

That's just a simple example, but the point is you can easily use the state of your segment to conditionally populate your tableView data source.

**Edit:** See the [UISegmentedControl Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html) for more info on `selectedSegmentIndex` and other properties and methods you can use.

Comment: I forgot to edit my pasted code above to reflect my example. iVar names should all be true to the example now.